# rotate string from back to front each character

Tags: android, string

please help,

I have string is 7865, how to rotate that string to be 5687.

whether using a loop or simply call the method lastIndexOf ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use StringBuffer for reverse string.

```
String string="5678";
      String reverse = new StringBuffer(string).
      reverse().toString();
      System.out.println("\nString before reverse:
      "+string);
      System.out.println("String after reverse:
      "+reverse);
```

Comment: Welcome,Small request Search well before posting :), Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can [reverse method of StringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) to achieve this :

```
StringBuilder stringToReverse= new StringBuilder("7865");
String reverseString = stringToReverse.reverse().toString();
```

Hope it helps ツ